# Having trouble configuring Code:Blocks to work

Tags: software-installation, g++

I seem to be having trouble in getting Code:Blocks to work properly within Ubuntu 14.04 lts. I simply installed it from the Software center, however everytime I try to build and run my code it does nothing, nothing at all. I keep trying to run the code but it seems to fail. **Note** I just checked and found that it does return an error:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -c "/home/james/Documents/C++ Projects/bin/sh: l: g++: not found
```

If anybody could help me troubleshoot this error I would greatly appreciate it, it seems things are a lot more complicated to install on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Ubuntu Software Center, search for g++ (GNU C++ compiler) and install it if it has not already been installed. g++ is an optional package for Code::Blocks. Code::Blocks depends on either g++ or gcc in Ubuntu 14.04, and you can also install both g++ and gcc.

Code::Blocks will automatically detect the path to the g++ executable without any  configuration required.

Comment: Thank you so much I can finally get back to learning. Thanks alot.